# How to use find() without changing​ the Matcher's state?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
class someclass {
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("\\G regex1");
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\\G regex2");
    Matcher matcher; 

    public void parse(str) { 
        matcher = pattern1.matcher(str);
        if(matcher.find() {
            method1();
        }
        else if(matcher.usePattern(pattern2).find())
            method2();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to test for a match without consuming the capturing group? I've tried to match against lookahead pattern `"\G(?=pattern)"` but it does not work. I need the captured string both in the parent method `parse()` and in the called methods `method1()` or `method2()` ; but the called methods look for it at the matcher's input.

Comment: What is code in `method1` and `method2` and what is input string?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE so that we could paste the code and see how it works. Add details: 1) what is wrong, 2) what it should behave like. "`\G(?=pattern)`" but it does not work" is a wrong kind of feedback - why doesn't it? It matches start of  string that starts with `pattern`.

Comment: Did you try `Matcher.reset()`?

Comment: I need to keep the previous state. I need to remember where the last match ended.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell the matcher not to consume the capturing group, however you can reset it to discard its internal state and start again from the beginning of the string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d)"); // single digit
String myString = "12345";
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(myString);

if(matcher.find()) { // expecting 1
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
if(matcher.find()) { // expecting 2
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
if(matcher.find()) { // expecting 3
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
matcher.reset(); // discard internal state, next find() will return 1 again


if(matcher.find()) { // expecting 1
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
1
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/A3mjN5)

Comment: reset() discards the position of `\G` but I need it. I can't start over from the beginning of the input.